# Prove: $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t}\ln\big(\int_0^1 e^{-tf(x)}dx\big) = -\min \ f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Let $f$ be a continuous function $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Prove:

1. $\forall \ t> 0;\frac{1}{t}\ln\Big(\int_0^1 e^{-tf(x)}dx\big) \le -\min \ f(x)$
2. $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t}\ln\big(\int_0^1 e^{-tf(x)}dx\big) = -\min \ f(x)$

I solved 1) Let $L =\min \ f(x)$ so :

$\frac{1}{t}\ln(\int_0^1 e^{-tf(x)}dx) \le \frac{1}{t}\ln(\int_0^1 e^{-tL}dx) = \frac{1}{t}\ln(e^{-tL}) = \frac{-tL}{t} = -L$

But I'm not sure how to bound it from below or how to use another method to show the equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already established that the expression is less than or equal to $-L$ for any $t>0$, so the same must be true in the limit as well.

Now fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let $$I_{\varepsilon}\equiv\{x\in[0,1]\,|\,f(x)<L+\varepsilon\}.$$ Note that the set $I_{\varepsilon}$ has positive Lebesgue measure. This is because $f$ is continuous, so whenever it attains its minimum value $L$, there will be a small open interval around the minimum-attaining point that is contained in $I_{\varepsilon}$.

Given that the exponential function returns positive values, integrating on a smaller domain (weakly) decreases the value of the integral. Therefore, one can establish the following:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\int_0^1e^{-tf(x)}\,\mathrm dx\right)&\geq\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\int_{I_{\varepsilon}}e^{-tf(x)}\,\mathrm dx\right)\\&\geq\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\int_{I_{\varepsilon}}e^{-t(L+\varepsilon)}\,\mathrm dx\right)=\frac{\ln\left(\int_{I_{\varepsilon}}\,\mathrm dx\right)-t(L+\varepsilon)}{t}.
\end{align*}
According to the observation made above, $\int_{I_{\varepsilon}}\,\mathrm dx>0$, so taking its logarithm is meaningful. Taking limit as $t\to\infty$, one can conclude that $$\liminf_{t\to\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\int_0^1e^{-tf(x)}\,\mathrm dx\right)\right\}\geq-L-\varepsilon.\tag{$\star$}$$ Take $\varepsilon$ as small as you like and you’re done.

---

Technically, we took $\liminf$ in $(\star)$ instead of $\lim$, because we hadn’t yet known whether the limit existed to begin with. We can then put together the pieces of the puzzle to conclude:
\begin{align*}
-L\geq\limsup_{t\to\infty}\,(\cdots)\geq\liminf_{t\to\infty}\,(\cdots)\geq-L.
\end{align*}
Therefore, the limits superior and inferior share the common value $-L$, which is then *the* limit of the expression. Proceeding this way, not only have we found the value of the limit but we have also established that it *exists* in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Use the continuity of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$.

Then, $f(x)$ attains a minimum, $f_{\min}$, at some point $x_0\in [0,1]$.  Then for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a neighborhood of $x_0$ for which

$$f_{\min}\le f(x)<f_{\min}+\varepsilon$$

Hence, for that $\varepsilon$ and neighborhood of $x_0$

$$ e^{-t\left(f_{\min}+\varepsilon\right)} \le e^{-tf(x)}\le  e^{-t\left(f_{\min}\right)}$$

Be careful to note that $f$ can attain its minimum at more than one point on $[0,1]$.